# First android studio project not building

Tags: java, android

Good day, I wanted to learn android development so I downloaded android studio. After downloading and installing all the sdk I get an error while the opening build starts.

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'.
```

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom'.
> > Connect to 161.158.114.70:8090 [/161.158.114.70] failed: Connection timed out: connect
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom'.
> > Connect to 161.158.114.70:8090 [/161.158.114.70] failed: Connection timed out: connect
> Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.5/google-services-4.3.5.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.5/google-services-4.3.5.pom'.
> > Connect to 161.158.114.70:8090 [/161.158.114.70] failed: Connection timed out: connect
> > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.5/google-services-4.3.5.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.5/google-services-4.3.5.pom'.
> > Connect to 161.158.114.70:8090 [/161.158.114.70] failed: Connection timed out: connect

This is the error I get and I have seen similar issues like this here and tried their solution but it does not seem to work for me. Please I need help

```java
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}
```

Comment: It feels like you have some sort of proxy server or something at `161.158.114.70`, and that proxy server is misbehaving.

Answer (score 0):

`jcenter()` is deprecated since end of march as you can see [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/jcenter-migration).

Replace `jcenter()` with `mavenCentral()`.

Comment: @AnthonyEghwrudje Okay, but what I said is true. Keep `mavenCentral()` instead of `jcenter()`.